# How to prepare a dataset for text classification

Tags: classification, text-mining, naive-bayes, caret, sentiment-analysis

I would like to compare some algorithms for performing sentiment classification (`Naive Bayes`, `SVM`, and `Random Forest`).
So far, I have collected about 100 000 unique opinions with the following distribution:

```
10% negative
90% positive
```

After some pre-processing (removing stop words, stemming etc) with `tm` package I obtained a document-term-matrix with about 320,000 unique terms (100% sparsity). I have decided to narrow it down to 99,8% sparsity ending with about 1 400 terms.

So by now my data set has about 100 000 rows and 1 400 columns.

To apply Naive Bayes classificator (from `klaR` package) I have changed each occurrence of term in document to a simple factor - YES or NO indicating if the term occurred in document or not.

The problem is when I'm trying to perform 10-fold CV almost all of the created data sets have some terms with zero variance. As far I understand changing the Laplace correction factor should face this problem (but it didn't). How to approach this problem? What are recommended practices?

Solutions that comes to my mind:

1. Reduce data set size (for example 10 000 opinions in each class)
2. Stop-words can be represented as terms (lower probability of zero variance)
3. Use bootstraping instead of 10-fold CV (but then the algorithm complains about the duplicated rows)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `nearZeroVar` function in `caret`. My opinion is that you are better off getting rid of extremely sparse *and* unbalanced predictors prior to model (or use a tree or other model that is not affected by such predictors).

Max

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to apply PCA to the data before running your algorithms.  This has many nice properties, including making all of your predictors orthogonal and relatively dense.